# Making a math equation for overtime

Tags: excel, algorithm, math, symbolic-math, algebra

right now i have an employee who is getting 500 dollars overtime when he works 40 hours and his basic salary is 3500 dollars, i need to have an equation to calculate the amount of dollars when he work any other amount of hours different salary or  with basic salary 4000 dollars. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, and not about programming.

Comment: well , its about Math actually

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are leaving out a few details but here is what I came up with for what I think you are looking for.

```
=IF(C2>40,A2+B2*(C2-40),A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming the algorithm you are looking for is an excel formula since you put an excel tag on it. Otherwise, everyone is correct in saying this isn't a coding question.